# Adding update property to mutation function breaks mocked result in MockProvider

Tags: next.js, graphql, apollo-client, graphql-js

I've got the following function that gets triggered on a form submission

```
const [register, { loading }] = useMutation(RegisterDocument);

const router = useRouter();

const onSubmit = async (values: FormValues) => {
  const v = { ...values };
  delete v.confirmPassword;
  const res = await register({
    variables: { options: v },
    update: (cache, { data }) => {
      cache.writeQuery<MeQuery>({
        query: MeDocument,
        data: {
          __typename: 'Query',
          me: data?.register.user,
        },
      });
    },
  });
  if (res.data?.register.user) {
    router.push('/');
  }
};
```

I then have the following test to submit the form

```
test('it should submit form without error', async () => {
  const firstName = faker.name.firstName();
  const surname = faker.name.lastName();
  const username = faker.internet.userName().replace('@', '');
  const email = faker.internet.email();
  const password = faker.internet.password(6, false, /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$/);

  const cache = new InMemoryCache().restore({});

  const variables = {
    options: { email, firstName, password, surname, username },
  };

  const user = { email, firstName, surname, username, id: 1, activated: false, photo: null };

  const mocks = [
    {
      request: { query: RegisterDocument, variables },
      result: { data: { register: { errors: null, user } } },
    },
  ];

  const { queryByTestId, container } = renderWithTheme(
    <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} cache={cache}>
      <Register />
    </MockedProvider>,
  );

  await updateRegisterInputs(container); // util function that updates input values for submission

  await submitForm({ queryByTestId, testId: 'register-submit', loadingTestId: 'register-loading' }); // util function that submits form

  await waitFor(() => expect(onPush).toBeCalledWith('/'));
});
```

When I run this test `res` returns the following

```
{ data: { register: {} } }
```

However, once I remove the `update` property inside the `register` mutation function, `res` returns the following.

```
{ data: { register: { errors: null, user: [Object] } } }
```

Any ideas why the mocked return value returns an empty object for the `register` property only when the `update` property function is added?

Even just instantiating the `update` property like so;

```
update: () => {}
```

still breaks the response from the mutation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that the graphql doc required the `__typename` property in the relevant places in my mocks

So I have to update the mock to include the typenames.

```
const user = { email, firstName, surname, username, id: 1, activated: false, photo: null, __typename: 'User' };

const mocks = [
  {
    request: { query: RegisterDocument, variables },
    result: { data: { register: { errors: null, user, __typename: 'UserResponse' } } },
  },
];
```